# Save Color to ViewState

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have a custom control with a panel wrapping all the other controls.  The control is in one of two states, edit-mode and normal.  When in edit-mode I want the control to have the option of a different background color.

I have:

In Pre_Render:

```
Panel1.BackColor = EditMode ? BackEditColor : BackColor;
```

And the control properties:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Misc")]
[Description("The background color.")]
[DefaultValue("white")]
[Localizable(true)]
public Color BackColor
{
    get { return Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(ViewState["BackColor"] ?? "white")); }
    set { ViewState["BackColor"] = value.Name; }
}

[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Misc")]
[Description("The edit-mode background color.")]
[DefaultValue("#FFFFCC")]
[Localizable(true)]
public Color BackEditColor
{
    get { return Color.FromName(Convert.ToString(ViewState["BackEditColor"] ?? "#FFFFCC")); }
    set { ViewState["BackEditColor"] = value.Name; }
}
```

I can set the colors with no problem via the control's properties, but they only show as white on render.  How should I be saving/reading to ViewState the colors?

Comment: Have you verified that the `Pre_Render` method is getting invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
public Color BackColor
{
    get { return (Color)(ViewState["BackColor"] ?? Color.White); }
    set { ViewState["BackColor"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus - I'd just come up with that myself, and for the default for the BackEditColor I used Color.FromName("#FFFFCC").

Answer (score 1):

Color.FromName("#FFFFCC") will not work, because it only works on predefined names like 'black'.

You can simply put the Color objects themselves in the viewstate.

Comment: No, you need to use the ColorTranslator for that: `ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFCC");`

Comment: It sets the name, but it does not set the actual color. And that causes your problem. I tried _int redPart = Color.FromName("#FFFFFFFF").R;_ This returns 0 instead of 255.